# From string in 24 hours to timestamp

Tags: oracle

I have a table with one column giving me dates in the form 24-JUL-17 and another column a string telling me the hour in the form hh:mm:ss.several_decimals but they are in 24 hours and not AM/PM, could someone point me on how I can add a column in oracle that combines them both into a timestamp?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask], and edit the question with sample input data (including table column definitions), and expected output, and what you have tried.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`CAST` the date to a timestamp data type and use `TO_DSINTERVAL` to convert the time column to a `DAY TO SECOND INTERVAL` and then add one to the other:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4dbcfc/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  date_column DATE,
  time_column VARCHAR2(15)
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( date_column, time_column ) 
  VALUES ( DATE '2017-06-24', '12:34:56.789012' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CAST( date_column AS TIMESTAMP )
       + TO_DSINTERVAL( '+0 ' || time_column ) AS datetime
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4dbcfc/1/0)**:

```
|                   DATETIME |
|----------------------------|
| 2017-06-24 12:34:56.789012 |
```

Comment: Thank you. I have not look into "CAST" but I will use this example to do so!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a fabricated table.

```
WITH test_data AS (
    SELECT
        SYSDATE date_val,
        '14:23:15.123' AS time_val
    FROM
        dual
) SELECT
    to_timestamp(TO_CHAR(date_val,'MM/DD/YYYY')
                   || ' '
                   || time_val,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
  FROM
    test_data
```

Comment: Thanks! This also helps me with how to rewrite the date in another string format.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate both input strings with `||` and convert it with `TO_TIMESTAMP`. The format is a bit tricky, took me a while to get it right.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mydate VARCHAR2(9), mytime VARCHAR2(20), mytimestamp TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO mytable (mydate, mytime) VALUES ('24-JUL-17', '22:56:47.1915010');
```

Test it

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(mydate||mytime, 'DD-MON-YYHH24:MI:SS.FF9') FROM mytable; 
2017-07-24 22:56:47,191501000
```

Or, in a table:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET mytimestamp = TO_TIMESTAMP(mydate||mytime, 'DD-MON-YYHH24:MI:SS.FF9');
```

Comment: Thank you! I was failing on the command (I was using to_date), and I didn't know the ff9. I also was adding an extra space in between ||' '|| and I see it is not necessary.